# XSLT 2 - variable value in for-each-group group-by

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

While in the process of porting some XSLT 1 code to XSLT 2, I came across this little snippet:

```
generate-id( ) = generate-id(key('key_name', concat($variable, '+', ../../@property_name, '+', node_name)))
```

I have seen this before, and found out it is known as Muenchian Grouping - a way to group nodes in XSLT 1, as for-each-group wasn't available at the time.

In XSLT 2, this could be written as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="xpath_here" group-by="concat($variable, '+', ../../@property_name, '+', node_name)">
```

What strikes me as odd though, is the use of `$variable` inside the grouping syntax. `$variable` has been previously declared and contains a single node with a value.

My question is - does `$variable` actually serve a purpose, or is it simply redundant? Or rather, to simplify, could a variable that points to a static value outside the scope of the elements being grouped affect the grouping in any way?

Comment: You might want to show a minimal but complete sample of XML input, XSLT 1.0, XSLT 2.0, wanted result, result you get, to allow us to judge that. We at least need to see the `xsl:key` definition and the context of the grouping to tell whether the value of the variable is the same for all uses or differs. In general, if a key contains the concatenation of different values, then it depends on those different values as a whole. XSLT 3.0 is introducing so called `composite` keys for that to avoid having to do string concatenation.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the comment. I can't provide XML input at the moment, however I've edited the above to try and generalize the question. The value of the variable is the same for all uses.